# Using PHP To build a form but having trouble naming with square brackets

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use PHP to build HTML that I will later display. I have the following lines:

```
$currentName = "test";
$numberToGiveDropDownHTML = "<Select name='$currentName[]'>\n";
```

But I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   ']', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE
>   or T_NUM_STRING in...

What is wrong with that? I thought I could that and later use the $_POST super global.

Thanks!

Comment: PHP's seeing the [] as an array reference, but there's no key, which is not allowed, you're not doing an assignment. `echo $array[]` is bad, but `$array[] = 7;` is permitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will try to parse variables in a double string automatically. Consider the following:

```
$a = 'foo';
echo "A = $a"; // output: A = foo
```

PHP will convert $a to foo for you, given it's in double quotes. In your scenario, it's thinking (the parser that is) that the `[]` is part of the in-line variable.

You can do one of two things: use `{$currentname}` so the parser doesn't keep going, or break the string out and concatenate the variable in, e.g. `...".$currentname."[]...`

Comment: Oops, Freudian slip. I had `$foo` instead of `$a`. ;-)

Comment: I don't think that's a Freudian slip, unless your mother's name is `$foo`.

Comment: @Dan: Wait, is that when you say one thing, but mean a mother? ;p It's more common to [generalize the usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudian_slip) to a slip of the tongue, but point taken.

Comment: It's called a Freudian slip when your misstatement reveals an unconscious train of thought. The most common examples are swapping in a word with sexual overtones for a similar sounding word. Freudian slip is a subset of slip of the tongue, not a synonym. Swapping two meaningless variable names in a code sample is not a Freudian slip, it's just a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$currentName = "test";
$numberToGiveDropDownHTML = "<Select name='{$currentName}[]'>\n";
```

Or:

```
$currentName = "test";
$numberToGiveDropDownHTML = "<Select name='$currentName" . "[]'>\n";
```

Either should work...

Good luck!

Comment: @lanP: Have a quote mis-match there. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That brackets are referencing an array, but $currentName isn't an array.